# How to detect application mode in Play 2.x

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

From within a Play 2.1 application, how would I programmatically determine which mode the application is running in (i.e., *Development* vs. *Production*)?

For example, it would be useful to be able to do something like this from inside a template:

`<p>@if(__some_play_API_call__ == Dev) { <b>Development mode</b> }</p>`

In the Play 2.0 API documentation, there appears to be a `mode` property of the `play.api.Application` *class*... however, I am unsure about how to get at the *instance* of the currently running application.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can access the current Appliction via

```
play.api.Play.current()
```

to find out the mode try

```
play.api.Play.current().mode()
```

or simply use

```
play.api.Play.isDev(play.api.Play.current())
```

Comment: In play 2.4.2 I had to use `play.api.Play.current` instead of `play.api.Play.current()`

Answer (score 19):

In Play 2.5.x the `play.Play.isDev()` method is deprecated, one has to use [dependency injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDependencyInjection):

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Example {

    @Inject
    private play.Environment environment;

    public void myMethod() {
        if (environment.isDev()) {
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

Or equivalently in Scala:

```
class ErrorHandler @Inject()(environment: Environment) {

  def myMethod() = {
    if (environment.isDev) {
      ...
    }
  }

}
```

`environment.isDev()` returns a Boolean, which one can easily pass to a template. No need to use implicit variables as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32971028/873282).

Comment: This answer is correct, but god this is needlessly verbose. Why is play promoting an unsafe and verbose pattern like dependency injection ?

Comment: @koppor Where do we initialize the `environment` variable? When I do 

@Inject
private play.Environment environment;

the environment here throws a NullPointerException, when I try to do environment.isProd( ). I am using JAVA

Answer (score 13):

With **Play 2.5**, **Play 2.6** and  **Play 2.7**

You can do it like this:

```
import play.Environment

class MyController @Inject()(env: Environment) {

  println(s"DevMode is ${env.isDev}")
  println(s"ProdMode is ${env.isProd}")
  println(s"TestMode is ${env.isTest}")

}
```

Or in **Play 2.6** and  **Play 2.7** you have also the version with `play.api.Environment`:

```
import play.api.Environment

class MyController @Inject()(env: Environment) {

  println(s"ProdMode is ${env.mode == Mode.Prod}")
  println(s"DevMode is ${env.mode == Mode.Dev}")
  println(s"TestMode is ${env.mode == Mode.Test}")
}
```

For both the Scala Doc states:

```
/**
 * The environment for the application.
 *
 * Captures concerns relating to the classloader and the filesystem for the application.
 */
```

Comment: Actually these no longer work in Play 2.6 (tested on 2.6.20). [Use `env.mode` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52755624/56285).

Comment: @Jonik See my adjusted response - seems there are 2 possibilities for the same;)

Answer (score 10):

In play 2.3.X you can also check via:

```
play.Play.isProd()
play.Play.isDev()
play.Play.isTest()
```

Comment: how does play know if it is in Dev or Prod?

Comment: It all depends on the way you start the application. More details here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production

Answer (score 5):

In Play 2.5 using Scala there is a `context.environment.mode` value of `Enumeration` from `play.api.Mode` with one of the values `Dev, Test, Prod`.
For compile time dependency injection you have `context` available in your app loader and if you extend `BuiltInComponentsFromContext` then you can use (inject) directly `environment.mode`

Answer (score 0):

In **Play 2.6**, inject an `Environment` instance and use its `mode` field: one of [`play.api.Mode`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/Mode$.html) enum values.

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.Environment
import play.api.Mode.Prod
import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, ControllerComponents}

class TestController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, env: Environment)
    extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def hello = Action {
    if (env.mode == Prod) {
      // ...
    }

    Ok(s"Hello world in ${env.mode} mode")
  }

}
```

At least in Play 2.6.20, the methods `env.isDev`, `env.isProd`, etc, [mentioned by pme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49150232/56285), no longer work.

Comment: The question is how to do that inside a template, not in a controller