# Play Framework 2.4 use injected variable in Scala template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I would like to show some data from the database in the menubar of my web page. To get the data, I have a data-access-object (DAO) which is usually created with Guice injection.

**How can I use such an (injected) object in my Scala templates?**

I could pass it as a parameter to the template, but I had to do this on every single page (because it should be displayed in the menubar). I'm looking for another solution where I don't have to pass it everywhere. Currently I'm creating a new object inside the template, whenever it is rendered (which gets me a cleaner code but a worse performance).

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward way to achieve what you want, but I think the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629250/how-to-avoid-passing-parameters-everywhere-in-play2) can help.

Comment: Can you abstract menubar in a separate template to avoid passing the parameter in every template?

Comment: @BhashitParikh: Thanks for the link, it indeed is a viable option. However, still not one I wished for.

Comment: @Adi: My menubar template is already in a separate template. However I'm calling it from all other templates and so had to provide the parameters via them nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can kinda-sorta fake this without too much effort.

First, create a Scala object that provides access to your DAO (this can contain as many things as you want, just repeat the pattern within the top-level object and the Implicits object).

```
package com.example.stuff

object ViewAccessPoint {
  private[stuff] val myDaoCache = Application.instanceCache[MyDao]

  object Implicits {
    implicit def myDao(implicit application: Application): MyDao = myDaoCache(application)
  }
}
```

In your view, you can then import the Implicits object into your template and get hold of the DAO created by Guice.

```
@import com.example.stuff.ViewAccessPoint.Implicits._
@import play.api.Play.current

myDao.whatever()
```

This works for both Java and Scala projects.

You can see this in practice here:

- [Access point](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/java/ViewAccessPoint.scala)
- [Template](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/java/views/restrict.scala.html#L7)

On a side note, I would consider if you really want to be doing data access in your template layer.

Comment: Thanks, you just saved me a lot of time of not having to pass in the object to over 100+ templates.

Comment: In your template you also need to `@import play.api.Play.current` to make this work.

Comment: @Itchy I'm trying to do the same thing, and I'm getting a compiler warning that use of `@import play.api.Play.current` is deprecated.  Do you know how this could be done with DI?  I'm using Play 2.5 btw

Comment: @RyanStull it's deprecated but you still need to do it that way.  I think DI for templates will be supported from 2.6 onwards. Alternatively, you can use twirl 1.2 - see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/SSPvSK-6oZU/Nu1eSBY8AwAJ) for some details.