# Good practice of using variables with template

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

I have recently started to work with play framework and working on a simple web project right now.

I am dealing with HTML templates so far and now I want to move some static values somewhere (f.x. version of application, name of application)

I have found only 3 ways so far:

1. Create java get/set object and pass it to template.
2. Declare variables inside of template and use them.
3. Add variables conf/application.conf

I do not like 1-st and 2-nd and would prefer to use 3-th way, however I do not want to mess with application.conf therefore I was thinking about new config file (like variables.conf or so) where I will save all static variables. I also want to make sure I can deal with i18n in future.

I would be very glad to see either a link where it is described or about todo-steps what needs to be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate `.conf` file and import it from `application.conf`, e.g.

```
play {
    // regular config
}

include "custom.conf"
```

where `custom.conf` is just another HOCON file, e.g.

```
application.constant.version=1
application.constant.name="foo"
```

You can also do the `include` within a nested point in your `application.conf`, at which point the values will be nested, e.g.

```
play {
    // regular config
    include "custom.conf"
}
```

would lead to the included values being in the `play` namespace, e.g.

```
play.application.constant.version=1
play.application.constant.name="foo"
```

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ConfigFile#Include-syntax for more details.

Comment: Steve, what about i18n?
How would you handle cases with localised variables?

Comment: Do i18n with the [standard  support](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaI18N)

Comment: how to access the variables from config on a view? can u please add an example? I cant find good one.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32971028/1063929)